# Excel: finding a given number criteria meeting cells from right to left

Tags: excel-formula

I need to find the average of 8 last (rightmost, from right to left) numeric cell values in a row that meet simple criteria of >= 0, ie. zero or positive numbers from rows that contain a mix of zeroes, and negative and positive values. In other words, I need to find the 8th cell reference from all cells containing 0 or higher counting from the end of the row backwards.

Example row:

```
1.6425  0.6233  5.2899  4.4372  2.0356  3.9796  1.5306  3.8344  0   -1  -1  3.8294  -1  3.0957  0   3.7572  -1
```

Expected result:
2.50
(3.7572 + 0 + 3.0957 + 3.8294 + 0 + 3.8344 + 1.5306 + 3.9796) / 8

Comment: Are you happy with a user defined VBA function?

Comment: Unfortunately no. With iterative function support this would be pretty trivial, the question pertains to internal Excel functions only. I could live with copying only the zero and/or positive cells from the row elsewhere (for example to another sheet) making a count of the copied cells and then taking an offset 8 cells before the last. But the most effective solution for me would be one answering the question directly.

Comment: Both solutions offered so far have answered the question directly - let us know if they work for your setup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this cleanly using `AVERAGEIFS` and adding only one supplementary row **A2:Q2** to mark just the 8 cells required. This extra row counts backwards from the end of the row, iterating by one from the previous count (next cell to the right) *only if* the cell above in row 1 is *not* less than 0, with the formula `=IF(A1<0,B2,B2+1)` copied throughout row A2:Q2. This then acts as **criteria2** for the main formula i.e. **use the first 8 cells from the right with a value >=0**.

Then it's a simple `=AVERAGEIFS(A1:Q1, A1:Q1, ">=0", A2:Q2, "<9")` in cell **C4** to get the result. **C5** is a simple manual test against the calculated result.

Here's the Excel file: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4974539/averageifs_tweak.xlsx - and a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks both for your efforts, but eventually I went with Dave's solution, because the actual multisheet file I need to work with is much more complicated than the simplification I offered as a question. Dave's solution is easier to maintain, which is a big plus in otherwise uncommented code.

Comment: thanks, glad to help - perhaps you should upvote both answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem but with plenty of auxiliary columns. In the following I assume you have your data in columns A to Q, starting in row 2

1. On the first row, put letters A to J in columns T to AC
2. On the first data row

   2.1 Put the forumula `=ROW()` in column S

   2.2 Put array formula (press Shift + Ctrl + Enter when entering it) `=SUM(IF(INDIRECT(T$1 & $S2 & ":Q" & $S2,TRUE)>=0,1,0))` to column T and copy it right all the way to column AC

   2.3 Enter array formula `=INDEX($T$1:$AC$1,MATCH(8,T2:AC2,0))` in column AD

   2.4 Finally, put array formula `=SUM(IF(INDIRECT(AD2 & S2 & ":Q" & S2) >= 0, INDIRECT(AD2 & S2 & ":Q" & S2), 0))/8` to column AE, this is the result you want
3. You can copy the row with formulas down to every row with data

This is how it looks in my Excel:
[image: screenshot]

What it does:

- in column S is the current row -- we need it for the `INDIRECT` function, because `ROW()` does not work in `INDIRECT` in array functions.
- in columns T - AC we count the number of columns in the right side of the current row of data that are positive or zero, starting in different columns -- their letters are on the first row. The rightmost column where we can start is J, otherwise there would not be
  8 values.
- in column AD we match number 8 and from the first row we get the column where we have to start the range for averaging
- finally, in column AE we use `INDIRECT` to create the reference to the range we want, sum all the numbers that are >= 0 and divide by 8

Comment: This is something along the lines I was thinking about. The extra columns for counting won't matter, as long as internal functions will suffice. Thanks Martin.

Comment: Ah - just posting my answer after working on it all day, when Martin's reply cropped up!